# Highcharts Export Server deployment to Service Fabric

Tags: highcharts, azure-service-fabric

So I am building an application that will be hosted on azure service fabric. Is it possible to run Highcharts Export Service on SF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run just about any executable in Service Fabric using the Guest Executable service type. Highcharts appears to be a Node JS application so it should be possible.

[More information regarding guest executables can be found in the MS docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app)